# Converting a WMS GetFeatureInfo's specific feature as hyperlink through GeoExt

Tags: openlayers, wms, geoext, getfeatureinfo

I'm tying to develop a WMS GetFeatureInfo query using GeoExt, OpenLayers and GeoServer and I want a hyperlink to be displayed on the popup window in a specific column. I have created the service but the link is returned as plain text.

I want to modify the content of the GeoExt window's content in order to convert that field to hyperlink. 
I read several answers in similar questions like:
[OpenLayers - URL hyperlink in GetFeatureInfo table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/openlayers-url-hyperlink-in-getfeatureinfo-table)

I succeed to convert the WMS GetFeatureInfo response to a hyperlink in GeoServer 'layer preview' template but when I use the same layer in my GeoExt app the content is plain text.
Also I read a way to convert GeoExt popup content in the following thread:
http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2011-July/002412.html

But I feel that the solution in my case is much simpler.
My code:

```
 var gfiControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            // autoActivate: true,
             drillDown: true,
             infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
             maxFeatures: 3,
             eventListeners: {
                "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {
                 var items = [];
                 Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                    items.push({
                       xtype: "propertygrid",
                       title: feature.fid,
                       source: feature.attributes
                  });
             });
             if (items.length > 0) {
                Ext.create('GeoExt.window.Popup', {
                   title: "Feature Info",
                   width: 350,
                   height: 320,
                   layout: "accordion",
                   map: mapPanel,
                   location: e.xy,
                   items: items
                  }).show();
                 }
               }
             }
          });
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I created a content.ftl template in my GeoServer and the direct response from GeoServer works fine.
After the @nmtoken's helpful comments and more searching, I realized that the main issue is that my GeoExt code cannot parse the html response from GeoServer. My GeoExt code now looks like that:

```
var gfiControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            // autoActivate: true,
             drillDown: true,
             infoFormat: "text/html",
             maxFeatures: 3,
             eventListeners: {
                "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {
                 var items = [];
                 Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                    items.push({
                       xtype: "propertygrid",
                       title: feature.fid,
                       source: feature.attributes
                  });
             });
             if (items.length > 0) {
                Ext.create('GeoExt.window.Popup', {
                  title: "Feature Info",
                   width: 350,
                   height: 320,
                   layout: "accordion",
                   map: mapPanel,
                   location: e.xy,
                   items: items
                  }).show();
                 }
               }
             }
          });
```

But while the ajax response has a status = 200, the popup window doesn't open.
When I copy and paste the query that is sent to the server to my browser, the response is successful just like in GeoServer's 'layer preview' page.
It seems like GeoExt cannot parse the response as infoFormat = text/html but only in infoFormat= "application/vnd.ogc.gml".
How can I fix this ?

Comment: `I'm developing a WMS GetFeatureInfo service` not quite sure what you mean, GetFeatureInfo is not  a service, it's an operation of a WMS service and goes in tandem with a GetMap operation.

Comment: To add the url of the request to the response, I would look at editing the [GeoServer template](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) used to create the response.

Comment: @nmtoken thanks for the response. I have created a GeoServer template adding a content.ftl file in GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/<datastore>/<featuretype>.  It works fine when the response is directly from GeoServer (as GeoServer's "layer preview" page). But when I use the same layer in my GeoExt app the result is plain text and not a hyperlink.

Comment: You'll need to specify the  info_format parameter as text/html

Comment: Do you mean to change infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml" ? Because I changed it but the result was the same.

Comment: The parameter name is info_format when you make a GFI request, but I see it is infoFormat in OL2, so yes.  Can you capture the actual request sent to the server?

Comment: The following url is the request that is sent to the server: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=oikismoi_2000_crete,rymotomia&QUERY_LAYERS=oikismoi_2000_crete,rymotomia&STYLES=,&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=2735597.869191%2C4138288.88834%2C2772440.51682%2C4187437.89752&FEATURE_COUNT=3&HEIGHT=643&WIDTH=482&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&X=331&Y=431  ... When I copy and paste on my browser the result is a table with a hyperlink ! But in my app the popup window doesn't open.